# Vim NERDTree. How to prohibit duplicate files in tabs?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I use NERDTree with the setting:

```
""""
" NerdTree
"
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Bundle 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
map <F2> :NERDTreeTabsToggle<CR>
```

I can open any number of tabs with the same file by pressing 't'. For example:

```
|foo.txt|bar.txt|foo.txt|foo.txt|
```

How to prevent the opening of duplicate files? I want to open an existing buffer by pressing 't'.

Comment: I don't know whether NERDTree supports doing this. IF you were loading the file manually, you could use `:tab drop {filename}` to open the file in a new tab, or jump to it if already open.

Comment: I find your issue to be common among many nerdtree users. I have submitted an issue on Github https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/439

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/439

> Grab the latest version and stick this in
>   ~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/override_tab_mapping.vim
>
> https://gist.github.com/scrooloose/0495cade24f1f2ebb602

Thanks @moeabdol

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand NerdTree does not have such a behavior. I believe however what you are looking for is either `:tab drop` like @Ben mentioned or using `:sb` to switch buffers with the following setting: `set swb=useopen,usetabe`.

Personally I would suggest you use NerdTree for more of a File Explorer and less of a file/buffer manager. By leveraging Vim's buffer commands you can easily switch between buffers. Additionally by using Vim's buffer commands you can avoid the "one-to-one: file-to-tab relationship trap" that so many new vimmers get stuck on.

#### Aside about NerdTree

NerdTree is very helpful to explore a complex or unfamiliar file structure, but it comes at the cost of taking up screen real estate and disrupting buffer and window/split workflows. See  [Oil and vinegar - split windows and the project drawer](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/) for more. Using a nice fuzzyfinder plugin like [CtrlP](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/) often takes the place of NerdTree for many people.

I have a nice post about NerdTree that might be of value: [Files, Buffers, and Splits Oh My!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23121220/438329)

#### Aside about tabs

Vim's tabs are not like most text editors tab. They are more like viewports into a group of windows/splits. Additionally, Vim is buffer centric, not tab centric like most editors. Therefore using features like the quickfix list is often easier without tabs (See `:h 'switchbuf` if you must use tabs). Vim's tabs often get in the way of using a splits as there are better window and buffer navigation commands available. I personally have many files open (sometimes 100+) use no tabs and use on average 1-2 splits without any issue. Bottom line: read the following posts:

- [Why do Vim experts prefer buffers over tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26708822/438329)
- [Use buffers effectively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329)

#### Best practices with Vim mappings

- Supply a mode. So `:map` becomes `:nmap`
- Unless using a `<Plug>` or `<SID>` mapping you should probably be using `:noremap`

By following these 2 rules your mapping will become:

```
nnoremap <f2> :NERDTreeTabsToggle<cr>
```

Comment: The NERDTree aside is easily solved by a mapping for `NERDTreeToggle` in conjunction with `let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 1`. "If we select a file in the project drawer, which split window will it appear in?" The one where I punched `<F2>`. "It is easy to imagine a scenario where the user mistakenly thinks that window C has the focus, when in fact the focus belongs to window A"? No, not if NERDTree is only open when I want to open something. It's like "I forgot if I'm in insert or command mode" - not if you only go into insert when inserting, and `<Esc>` the hell out the second you stop typing. Vim.

Comment: @Amadan I agree with Drew Neil in his [Oil and Vinegar](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/) blog post. I do not think your NerdTree setting really goes far enough. I personally use Tim Pope's [vinegar.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar). If you rather NerdTree instead of netrw dhruvasagar has a [NerdTree fork of vinegar.vim](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-vinegar).

Comment: I agree to the point that that having a permanent project drawer is a bad idea in Vim. But can you give any complaints to my config (for a temporary drawer) that are more specific than that? Why do you think it does not go far enough? (For full disclosure, I must say that I do use Ctrl-P or plain `:e` with tab-completion a lot of the time, but I do like NERDTree for exploration, as the author says.)

Comment: @Amadan, Personally I see little point in opening a temporary window when the window I am going to change will do just as well. It avoids disrupting my window layout, gives me a full window's width, and undo accidental exploring w/ a simple `<c-6>`. If you like CtrlP and `:e`  (check out `<c-d>` as well) you are going to love [Projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist). Projectionist is helpful if you have a structured project by creating custom navigation commands (with fuzzy completion!) as well as setting up alternative file navigation (Great for switching to test files).

Comment: The layout is restored as soon as I open something (or hit `<F2>` again), I know exactly where it will be and what its width will be (and a window might be tiny), and I use bufexplorer so accidental explore is still easy. I probably wouldn't mind having NERDTree in-window, it would make it a bit similar to bufexplorer, but I'm already used to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

to open a new buffer, just press `o`

Comment: It rewrite current buffer. I want open new tab if not exist or open exist tab.

Comment: @uralbash what do you mean "it rewrites current buffer"? it opens the file in a new buffer if it does not exist or opens the existing buffer.

Comment: @uralbash: You seem to be confused about the difference between buffers and windows.